# transform: translate é compatível com quais navegadores?

Tags: html

Exemplo de uso funciona bem em navegadores modernos a duvida é em quais versões não será compatível.

```
<h2 style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color:orange;">Centralizado</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| Feature       | Chrome        | Firefox (Gecko)            | Internet Explorer | Opera         | Safari     |
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| Basic support | (Yes) -webkit | 3.5 (1.9.1)-moz16.0 (16.0) | 9.0 -ms10.0       | 10.5-o12.5    | 3.1-webkit |
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| 3D Support    | 12.0-webkit   | 10.0-moz16.0 (16.0)        | 10.0              | Não suportado | 4.0-webkit |
+---------------+---------------+----------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
```

Note que para algumas versões é preciso usar -XXXX (ex: -webkit)

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com o CanIUse.com, esta é a situação atual:

[image: Gráfico do Can I Use]

Note que este gráfico é dos 2D Transforms como um todo, o que inclui o translate.

Os ítens marcados com `[1]` não suportam CSS Transform em SVG

Ainda, há que se nota isto:

- Abaixo do FF42, o `transform-origin` não funciona em SVG também.
  In IE9 the caret of a textarea disappears when you use translate.
- No Android 2.3 a escala não afeta o *background*.

Link:

> https://caniuse.com/#search=translate